# Comparing procedure parameter with cursor values

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am writing below code. Comparing procedure IN parameter with cusrsor values.

```
create or replace procedure  dashboard_addtion(customer_name IN varchar2)
IS
num number:=0;
CURSOR cname_cur 
    IS Select customername from customer_master;
cname varchar2(300);
begin
    for cname in cname_cur loop
        if upper(cname.customername)!=upper(customer_name) then
            num:=num+1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    if num != 0 then 
        insert into customer_master select max(customerid) + 1, customer_name
        from customer_master;
    end if;
end;
```

All the time its executing INSERT statement.

Comment: The title doesn't seem related to the question, though I'm not entirely sure what the question is. You're looping over all existing records and counting those that don't match your parameter; and if *any* don't match then you're inserting a new record. Are you really trying to insert a new record only if one matching the parameter does not exist? You don't need a cursor for that.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes Alex i am trying to insert new record,Only if it is already not present.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes i know its possible without using cursor. But i just want to have clear picture about cursor how it works, Please Suggest TY :)

Comment: There's a lot of variable name confusion in there, and a misspelling in the procedure name -- all of that will drive you and coworkers crazy in a real development environment. Name your PL/SQL variables the same as the database columns that they are equivalent to, and namespace them with the PL/SQL block name when you use them in a SQL statement (eg. "customer_master.customer_name = dashboard_addition.customer_name").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis you explicitly want to experiment with cursors... you seem to have the logic for the `num` increment and check backwards:

```
for cname in cname_cur loop
  if upper(cname.customername) = upper(customer_name) then
    num := num+1;
  end if;
end loop;
if num = 0 then 
  insert into customer_master
  select max(customerid)+1,customer_name from customer_master;
end if;
```

This will count the cursor records that *do* match your parameter, and only do an insert if *none* were found.

It might be clearer to use a `boolean` flag:

```
... is
  found boolean := false;
  cursor cname_cur is select custname from customer_master;
begin
  for cname in cname_cur loop
    if upper(cname.customername) = upper(customer_name) then
      found := true;
    end if;
  end loop;
  if not found then
    insert into customer_master
    select max(customerid)+1,customer_name from customer_master;
  end if;
end;
```

Also note that you don't need to declare `cname` explicitly; it's redeclared as part of the `for ... in ... loop` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I May need your more help to get comfortable with PL/SQL :)